# Can't transfer cookbook to Windows node using Chef Kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, winrm, test-kitchen

I've been stuck trying to converge my test cookbook with Chef Kitchen.

I've tried tinkering with the settings and using different vagrant boxes as well as "packing" my own.  But each time I still get this error:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #converge action: [[WinRM::Transport::FileTransporter] Upload failed (exitcode: 1)
#< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">The term 'Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was in_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">cluded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:3 char:2_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ . &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  Function Cleanup($o) { if (($o) -and ($o.GetType().GetMethod("Dispose_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">") -ne $null)) { $o.Dispose() } }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Function:String) [], CommandNot _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   FoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid character i_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">n a Base-64 string."_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:4 char:114_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ Function Decode-Base64File($src, $dst) {set-content -Encoding Byte -Path $dst_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> -Value ([Convert]::FromBase64String &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; ([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($src)))}_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzip-3395dca_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">1ace537199fc6ec84fb894f56.zip' because it does not exist._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:30 char:45_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+     $bytes = $c.ComputeHash(($in = (Get-Item &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  $src).OpenRead()))_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\vagran...c84fb894f56.z _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   ip:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetIt _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   emCommand_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">The term 'Cleanup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inc_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">luded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:32 char:50_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+   } catch [exception]{throw $_} finally { Cleanup &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  $c; Cleanup $in }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Cleanup:String) [], CommandNotF _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   oundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">The term 'Cleanup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inc_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">luded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:32 char:62_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+   } catch [exception]{throw $_} finally { Cleanup $c; Cleanup &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  $in }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Cleanup:String) [], CommandNotF _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   oundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:30 char:60_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+     $bytes = $c.ComputeHash(($in = (Get-Item $src).OpenRead &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; ()))_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (OpenRead:String) [], RuntimeE _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   xception_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Here's the screen output:

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.4.0)
-----> Creating <default-windows-2008r2>...
       Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
       ==> default: Importing base box 'windows-2008r2'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
       ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: kitchen-my_cookbook-default-windows-2008r2_default_1439924218684_94584
       ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
       ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
           default: Adapter 1: nat
       ==> default: Forwarding ports...
           default: 3389 => 3389 (adapter 1)
           default: 5985 => 5985 (adapter 1)
           default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
       ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
       ==> default: Booting VM...
       ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...    default: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:5985
           default: WinRM username: vagrant
           default: WinRM transport: plaintext
       ==> default: Machine booted and ready!
       ==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
       ==> default: Machine not provisioned because `--no-provision` is specified.
       [WinRM] Established
       Vagrant instance <default-windows-2008r2> created.
       Finished creating <default-windows-2008r2> (1m20.27s).
-----> Converging <default-windows-2008r2>...
       Preparing files for transfer
       Preparing dna.json
       Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 3.2.4...
       Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
       Preparing solo.rb
-----> Installing Chef Omnibus (install only if missing)
       Downloading package from https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/windows/2008r2/x86_64/chef-client-12.4.1-1.msi
       Download complete.
       Successfully verified C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\chef-true.msi

       Installing Chef Omnibus package C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\chef-true.msi
       Installation complete
       Transferring files to <default-windows-2008r2>
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #converge action: [[WinRM::Transport::FileTransporter] Upload failed (exitcode: 1)
#< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">The term 'Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was in_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">cluded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:3 char:2_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ . &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  Function Cleanup($o) { if (($o) -and ($o.GetType().GetMethod("Dispose_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">") -ne $null)) { $o.Dispose() } }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Function:String) [], CommandNot _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   FoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid character i_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">n a Base-64 string."_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:4 char:114_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ Function Decode-Base64File($src, $dst) {set-content -Encoding Byte -Path $dst_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> -Value ([Convert]::FromBase64String &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; ([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($src)))}_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzip-3395dca_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">1ace537199fc6ec84fb894f56.zip' because it does not exist._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:30 char:45_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+     $bytes = $c.ComputeHash(($in = (Get-Item &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  $src).OpenRead()))_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\vagran...c84fb894f56.z _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   ip:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetIt _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   emCommand_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">The term 'Cleanup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inc_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">luded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:32 char:50_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+   } catch [exception]{throw $_} finally { Cleanup &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  $c; Cleanup $in }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Cleanup:String) [], CommandNotF _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   oundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">The term 'Cleanup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inc_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">luded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:32 char:62_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+   } catch [exception]{throw $_} finally { Cleanup $c; Cleanup &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  $in }_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Cleanup:String) [], CommandNotF _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   oundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:30 char:60_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+     $bytes = $c.ComputeHash(($in = (Get-Item $src).OpenRead &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; ()))_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (OpenRead:String) [], RuntimeE _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   xception_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Here's my `.kitchen.yml`:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  forward_agent: yes
  communicator: winrm
  guest: windows

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  password: vagrant
  username: vagrant

transport:
  name: winrm

platforms:
  - name: windows-2008r2
    driver_config:
      vm_hostname: false
      guest: windows
      communicator: winrm
    os_type: windows
    shell_type: powershell
    transport:
      name: winrm

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[my_cookbook::default]
    attributes:
```

Here's my `metadata.rb`:

```
name 'my_cookbook'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures my_cookbook'
long_description 'Installs/Configures my_cookbook'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'apt', '~> 2.7.0'
depends 'java', '~> 1.35.0'
```

Here's my `recipes/default.rb`:

```
cookbook_file '/tmp/kitchen/cache/server-jre-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz' do
  source 'server-jre-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz'
  action :create
end

include_recipe 'apt'
include_recipe 'java'
```

Here's my `attributes/default.rb`:

```
node.override[:java][:jdk_version] = '8'
node.override[:java][:install_flavor] = 'oracle'

node.default['java']['jdk']['8']['x86_64']['url'] = 'file://server-jre-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz'
```

I've tried following these tutorials, but now I'm just stuck:

http://kitchen.ci/blog/test-kitchen-windows-test-flight-with-vagrant/

http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/orchestrating-multi-server-tests-in-test-kitchen

Please let me know what else I can try to troubleshoot this.

Thank you for your time!

I've hit the StackOverflow character limit, so I've attached the `kitchen.log` and output of `kitchen diagnose --all` here:

https://gist.github.com/alininja/0c212b01cff906a5b85d

Comment: Have you tried using the ChefZero provisioner by changing the name of the provisioner to "chef_zero".  Not sure if that will solve your problem but that's the one I use.  Also what versions of Vagrant, Chef and VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: Thanks @chief7, I'll give that I shot the next time I give this a go. We've put it on hold for now. Thanks again!